# How to store all records of topic in single file.?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How to store all information of kafka topic with all records details in file.

a) Can i get all records of KafkaTopic in single file.?

b) Where located topic details on kafka.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) You can try to extract all topic messages into a file

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic <TOPIC> --from-beginning > singlefile.txt
```

You can also add `--property print.key=true` to include the message key

You can use the file output to produce the data to into kafka.

b) 
You can get the topic partitions, configurations, and sync status with this command

```
kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <TOPIC>
```

You can get the topic settings with this command

```
kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --entity-type topics --entity-name <TOPIC>
```

You can use the add on every command and export them to the filesystem.

```
> simplefile.txt
```

Comment: @GerlandoCalara thank you, but this solution for cmd, can i get using kafka 2.0 api

Comment: @Kailas Every cmd function here is just a wrapper around a Java API call

Comment: @cricket_007 ok

Comment: the kafka-console-consumer command does not not exit (its like a tail -f). It monitors new input forever till you kill the process. So writing to the file will run forever as well. Is there some way to tell it to "stop when you reach the final offset". I have to dump a ton of data from a topic and dont have a clue when to kill it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think this tool may help you.
https://github.com/huantt/kafka-dump

> go install github.com/huantt/kafka-dump@latest
>
> kafka-dump export 
> --storage=file
> --file=path/to/output/data.parquet 
> --kafka-topics=users-activities 
> --kafka-group-id=id=kafka-dump.local 
> --kafka-servers=localhost:9092 
> --kafka-username=admin 
> --kafka-password=admin 
> --kafka-security-protocol=SASL_SSL 
> --kafka-sasl-mechanism=PLAIN